# Can a timelike curve catch up to a causal curve?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, causality

In Wald's *General Relativity*, Lemma 8.1.4, he proves that if $\gamma$ is a causal, past-directed, inextendible curve passing through $p$, then through any $q \in I^+(p) = \{\text{all points reachable from $p$ by future-directed timelike curves}\}$ there also exists a past-directed, inextendible curve.

The way he proves this is as follows. Because $q \in I^+(p)$, we must have $p \in I ^-(q) = \{\text{all points reachable from $q$ by past-directed timelike curves}\}$. In particular, we can connect $q$ to $p$ by a timelike curve and connect $p$ to any $\gamma(t)$ with the causal curve $\gamma$. It follows that $q$ can be connected to $\gamma(t)$ with a causal, non-null geodesic curve. By a previous theorem in the book, we can deform this curve into a purely causal path, and thus $\gamma(t) \in I^-(q)$ for all $t$.

Now, he lets $k$ be some positive definite metric on the spacetime which induces a metric $\text d$ and claims that, because $\gamma(1) \in I^-(q)$, we can find a timelike curve $\sigma$ starting from $q$ s.t.
$$ \text d (\sigma(t), \gamma(t)) \le C (1 + t)^{-1}$$
for $t \in [0, 1]$. I have no idea how to construct this curve. My first guess would be to connect $q$ to $\gamma(1)$ with a time-like curve but I don't think this guarantees that both curves are getting closer. Maybe the metric $k$ must play a role in the construction? Geroch in *Domain of Dependence* also claims something like this without any justification. Am I missing something obvious?